# Inserir no banco com função

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou tentando fazer uma inserção no banco de dados usando uma função porém não estou conseguindo inserir os respectivos valores;

### HTML:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submitTexto'])) {
                    inserir('empresa', $_POST);
                } ?>
```

onde `submitTexto`é um botão de enviar.

### Função:

```
<?php 

function conectar() {
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fap", "root", "");
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
return $pdo;
}

conectar();

function inserir($tabela, $dados) {
$con = conectar();
foreach ($dados as $dado => $valores) {
    $campo = array();
    array_push($campo, $dado);

    $valor = array();
    array_push($valor, $valores);

}
$campo = implode(',', $campo);
$valor = implode(',', $valor);

$inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela($campo) VALUES($valor)");
$inserir->execute();
if ($inserir->execute()){
    echo "Inserido com sucesso!";
}
else {
    echo "Erro!";
    print_r($con->errorInfo());
}
}
```

### Resultado:

> Erro! Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: Cola isso na sua função, pra gente testar ver se estão vindo os posts.    foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
     $dados[$key] = $val;   
   }
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($dados);
   echo "<pre>";
   die();

Comment: Imprima a sql, nesse insert só tem numero? da forma como está precisa escapar as strings com aspas simples. Chame `$inserir->execute()` uma vez só.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode elaborar dessa forma um `foreach()`, para que busque todos os campos postados e insira no banco de dados:

```
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
        $dados[$key] = $val;
        $campos = implode(",", $key); 
        unset($_POST["submitTexto"]);  
   }
```

Dessa forma, o nome do campo do banco de dados deverá ser o mesmo que o nome do campo.

Comment: Entendi o que você explicou André, muito obrigado! usei `$campo[] = $key;
        $valor[] = "'$val'";
        
        $campos = implode(",", $campo);
        $valores = implode(',', $valor);` para ficar mais facil para que eu entendesse futuramente.

Answer (score 1):

É possível simplificar a lógica e usa prepared statements, primeiro verifique quantos placeholders(interrogações) vai precisar esse número é baseado na quantia de valores passado em `$dados`, jogue placeholders na sql e por último faça o bind dos valores com as colunas, basta passar um array em `execute()` com os valores.

```
function inserir($tabela, $dados) {
    $campos = implode(", ", array_keys($dados));
    $values = implode(", ", array_values($dados));

    $totalInterrogacoes = count($dados);

    $interrogacoes = str_repeat('?,', $totalInterrogacoes);
    $interrogacoes = substr($interrogacoes, 0, -1); // remove a última virgula

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela($campos) VALUES($interrogacoes)";

    $con = conectar();
    $inserir = $con->prepare($sql);

    if($inserir->execute($values)){
       echo 'sucesso';
    }else{
        print_r($con->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A não ser que tenha somente números, e que os números de ponto flutuante sejam convertidos para string com ponto, a instrução deve falhar.

Como está usando o prepare, para ver o erro, use `print_r($inserir->errorInfo());` para ver o erro correto.

Não está usando a atribuição de valores do prepare, que é a maior vantagem, pois ele trata a limitação de strings com aspas, números, etc. Se for usar desta forma como está, melhor executar diretamente com `$con->query($query);` de uma vez.

Eu recomendo reconstruir para usar o tratamento de valores do prepare.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php